# Showing that every smooth 1-form is an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading the John Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds, Proposition 22.12 and stuck at showing that every smooth 1-form $\sigma : M \to T^{*}M$ is an immersion :

[image]

I am trying to understand the underlined statement. Why can we deduce that $\sigma$ is a immersion from the above coordinate representation? Why the rank of the matrix of partial derivatives of the coordinate representation is $n:=\operatorname{dim}M$ ?
I think that it seems possible to prove and stuck at making proof rigorously. I think that I am unfamilier to calculate the rank of the jacobian matrix. Can anyone helps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\pi \circ \sigma = Id_{M}$, their differentials  satisfy
$$
\forall p\in M,\quad (\pi_*)_{\sigma(p)} \circ (\sigma_*)_p = Id_{T_pM}.
$$
In particular, for any $p\in M$, $(\sigma_*)_p$ is injective, which is the definition of $\sigma$ being an immersion.

If you really want to use a matrix representation of $(\sigma_*)_p$, then differentiating the equality you have underlined gives a matrix representation of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & * & \cdots & *\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & * & \cdots & *
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which thus has maximal rank.

Comment: Wow, more easy route exists! And original method also works. Thank you !~

Comment: @Plantation I don't know which route is the easiest to guess and to digest, but the first one is surely easier to typeset!

Comment: :) O.K. ~~~~~~ !